# Windows server 2008 compatibility with dev-c++

Tags: windows-server-2008, dev-c++

Can i use `dev c++ 4.9.9.2` on `Windows Server 2008 R2`, i mean that i tried using it on windows 8 but it didn't run. And we are restricted to use this IDE only from our university.
`Server 2008 R2` is 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

According to their site,  Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 only supports Windows 9x, NT, or 2000.  Given that the Windows Server operating system series started in 2000 (with Windows Server 2000), and that Dev C++ 5 doesn't support it (even though it supports XP, a later released OS), I would surmise that it is not supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.  However, you should be able to run it if you use Compatibility Mode.

You can use the following steps: (from [How to Run Older Programs under Windows 8 -- For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-run-older-programs-under-windows-8.html) but copied down in case of link rot.  This technique also works in Windows Vista/7/Server 2008 R2)

> 1. **Right-click the program's icon and choose Properties.**
> 2. **When the Properties dialog box appears, click the Compatibility tab
>      and then click the Run Compatibility Troubleshooter button.**
>
>    In its robotic way, Windows 8 tries to guess what version of Windows
>      your program needs, and then it applies the changes. If the program
>      begins working, you're through.
>
>    If the program still has trouble, though, move to Step 3.
> 3. **In the Compatibility Mode section, select the Run This Program in
>      Compatibility Mode For check box and select the program's desired
>      Windows version from the drop-down list.**
>
>    [image: Compatibility Mode Selection Box]
> 4. **Check your program's box or look at its manual to see what version
>      of Windows it expects.**
> 5. Click OK and then try running your program again to see whether it
>      works better.
>
>    If your older program doesn't run, it's time to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: i am using it on `windows 7`. `Windows server 2008 R2` is based on `7 platform` so i reckon it can run on it properly.

Comment: There are some changes in the OS between the two.  Try running it in Compatibility Mode.